# Why does objdump show dot dot dot?

Tags: arm, objdump

I have an (ARM) object file that I want to inspect. There are some instructions that load addresses pointing to another area in the object file. I would like to see the contents of the area, but `objdump -Ds` shows `...` and skips the whole section. For example:

```
000230cc <heap_size_129>:
   230cc:       00000000        andeq   r0, r0, r0

000230d0 <small_integers>:
        ...

000231d8 <heap_size_33>:
   231d8:       00000000        andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Here, I need the contents of `small_integers`. Does `...` mean it is full of `andeq r0,r0,r0` (i.e., `null`)?

I cannot find other flags beside `-Ds` in the `objdump` manpage that may help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`...` are printed for repeated zero bytes, since that is usually filler data and not interesting. You can use `-z, --disassemble-zeroes` switch to force their disassembly anyway.